# Getting stackoverflow error while trying to inflate custom view

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have custom_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.example.MyCustomLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- different views -->

</com.example.MyCustomLayout>
```

And its class:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

public MyCustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);
    setUpViews();
    }
//different methods
}
```

And activity, which includes this layout:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    setUpViews();
}
```

And my_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.MyCustomLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <com.example.MyCustomLayout
        android:id="@+id/section2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, I have a problem when I remove comment block from: `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);` and go to my_activity.xml in graphic mode. Eclipse thinks and then crashes. It look like it tries to inflate my custom view many times but I don't understand why. I'am getting this error in error log when i relaunch eclipse: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `custom_layout.xml` replace `<com.example.MyCustomLayout` with another layout(for example a `LinearLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- different views -->

</LinearLayout>
```

or even better use the [`merge`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) tag(and set the `orientation` in the `MyCustomLayout` class). Right now when `Android` loads `my_activity.xml` it will find your custom `View` and it will instantiate it. When your custom view will be instantiated `Android` will inflate the `custom_layout` xml file in the `MyCustomLayout` constructor. When this happens it will once again find `<com.example.MyCustomLayout ...`(from the just inflated `custom_layout.xml`) which results in `MyCustomLayout` being instantiated again. This is a recursive call and it will finally throw the `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of this line

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, true);
```

in your constructor for the custom layout object is causing a infinite recursion of self-dependent calls, overflowing the stack.

There's no reason for you to be doing that.

Probably you best bet is to dig up an example of someone else's working custom layout class.

Comment: without this line - i got null when trying to findViewById

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not the right way to resolve it.  I'm suggesting you find someone's working example of a custom layout as a guide to the mechanics of how it is supposed to be done.